# Some more regex criteria in existing regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to add into below regex which also pass following criteria -

```
^[\p{L}\d'][ \p{L}\d'-]*[\p{L}\d'-']$
```

1. Should start with letter (A-Z or a-z) only.
2. Can accepts only single letter also.
3. Accept hyphen (`-`), Space, dot (`.`) in between the string or end of the string. (No other special character)
4. Accept numbers in between and end to the string.

Please also want to achieve existing criteria what this regex is doing.

E.g.

**Expected** -

```
t, T, test, test123, te12st, te-st, te.st, te st, éééééé, ṪỲɎɆḂɃɀȿȸȺȔȐȳɊÉâÇë, Επίθετο
```

**Not Expected** -

```
12test, 1, .test, -test, , tes*t (none of the special character except hyphen, dot & space),
```

Comment: `^\\p{L}[ \\p{L}\\d.-]*$`

Comment: To solve bullet point #1 you would need `^[A-za-z]{1}[\\p{L}\\d'][ \\p{L}\\d'-]*[\\p{L}\\d'-']$`

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected matches?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I have updated the question with expected matches.

Comment: How is `ṪỲɎɆḂɃɀȿȸȺȔȐȳɊÉâÇë` valid? It doesn't fit into the regex that you've presented nor the requirements you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted directly from java class so there was double slash in regex. I updated the question.

https://regex101.com/r/RrT3Qy/2 here you can see matching string

Comment: Try `^\pL[\d\pL .-]*$` https://regex101.com/r/LQa2Bc/1 Note that not all of the expected start with a-zA-Z

Comment: @ppb Did any of the given answers work out?

Comment: Yes. I am using anubhava's answer from first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z]+[\p{L}\d-.\s]*$
```

This is a possible solution, however these test criteria conflict with your first requirement: éééééé, ṪỲɎɆḂɃɀȿȸȺȔȐȳɊÉâÇë, Επίθετο. Where it 1) accepts one or more of A-Za-z then 2) zero or more combination of letters, numbers, hyphens, space, and periods.

If you want it to also accept those three test criteria then this is a possible solution:

```
^[\p{L}]+[\p{L}\d-.\s]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the expected and not the not expected including a single letter, you could match `\pL` from the start of the string. Then repeat 0+ times any of the listed in `[\d\pL .-]` and then assert the end of the string.

Note that not all of your expected start with a-zA-Z.

```
^\pL[\d\pL .-]*$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^\\pL[\\d\\pL .-]*$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQa2Bc/1/) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/H6ekbv)